# How to slice variable name on small screen sizes with Twig?

Tags: php, twig

To keep my table readable I would like to slice the variable name on mobile screens to 15 characters. How can I execute the code below so that it only shows on small screensizes?

```html
{{airline.name |length > 15 ? airline.name|slice(0, 15) ~ '...' :airline.name }}
```

Comment: You don't twig is run serverside and does not know about screensize. You might want to use [text-overflow](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server-side rendering engine like `twig` doesn't have access to a browser's size of the viewport.

The best-practice solution for cutting strings and attaching dots on lower screen-sizes is the CSS property `text-overflow` in combination with CSS media queries.

A pure CSS solution that cuts the text inside `.element` if the text doesn't fit into the element and adds 3 dots instead of automatically wrapping it to the next line(s) would look as follows:

```css
.element {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .element {
        overflow: visible;
        white-space: normal;
        text-overflow: none;
    }
}
```